# How to remove all whitespaces from a Json string

Tags: c#, json, string, serialization, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing all whitespace from a string efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865863/removing-all-whitespace-from-a-string-efficiently)
>   [Minify indented JSON string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913138/minify-indented-json-string-in-net)

I have a string like this:

```
{"languages" : [{"fluency": 4, "id": 15}], "address" : {"city_id" : 8341, "city_name" : "My city"}, "about" : null, "birthday" : "1988-03-18", "email" : "email@a.com", "id" : 3, "income" : 4}
```

I would like to have a compact/minified string like this:

```
{"languages":[{"fluency":4,"id":15}],"address":{"city_id":8341,"city_name":"My city"},"about":null,"birthday":"1988-03-18","email":"email@a.com","id":3,"income":4}
```

NOTE:

- I'm using the built in `System.Json` to perform serialization in my app. I retrieve the string representation of a `JsonValue` object using the `ToString ()` method, but looks like I have no control over the format of the output string.
- I'd like to use a helper method to 'minify' the JSON string. I don't want to include another third party Json library in the project.
- I'm using complex JSON data structures (including nested objects/arrays)
- I'm using Mono, not .NET

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Minify indented JSON string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913138/minify-indented-json-string-in-net)

Comment: @EricJ. I need to remove all whitespaces from a JSON string, not an arbitrary string. The final result would become `"address":{"city_id":8341,"city_name":"My city"}` (note the preserved space in `"My city"`

Comment: Best answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28456818/1912609. Code: string json = jObject.ToString(Formatting.None);