# Trim json string in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am using `JObject.ToString()` method to convert JSON object to string. But how can I trim output to delete spaces between tokens?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No need to resort to using Regex.  Just use the `Formatting.None` option:

```
string json = jObject.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myJson);

[Json.Net SerializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_1.htm)